# How to style buttons in Alert Dialog Fragment using Material Design?

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, material-design

I'd like to change the default button styling on an alert dialog.

The standard Alert Dialog Fragment (in Android L) looks like this:

[image: Default Alert Dialog Fragment]

I'd like the right button to be styled as a normal button instead of a borderless button. Google itself seems to use this pattern in various dialogs, such as:

[image: Dialog without borderless button]

Does anyone know if this is possible, without recreating the whole dialog from scratch?

Comment: You can assign a custom layout to a Dialog, including styled Buttons: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 4):

You can style the button in the theme with attributes: `android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle`, `android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle`, and `android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue is solved automagically by updating to the (just released) release 21. Now the buttons are automatically in primary color :-)

EDIT: They are not in primary color, but in Android's basic turquoise..

Comment: Did you solve this? how did you make the nice button as on the play store? About dialogs, I've made a library if you wish: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialStuffLibrary

Comment: I was not able to change the button type in the dialog. It now shows two turqoise borderless buttons

Comment: You should check out the sample that the library I've made is based on : https://github.com/fengdai/AlertDialogPro

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for changing button color with material effect in `AppCompatDialogFragment`.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="20dp"
android:text="@string/buttin"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.MyButton"
/>
```

### **Style file - v21**

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

### **Style file**

```
<style name="AppTheme.MyButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
  <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin**

1. In your app's theme/style, add the following lines:

   ```
   <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
   <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
   <item name="android:buttonBarNeutralButtonStyle">@style/NeutralButtonStyle</item>
   ```
2. Then add the following styles:

   ```
   <style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
   </style>

   <style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
       <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
   </style>

   <style name="NeutralButtonStyle" 
   parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog">
       <item name="android:textColor">#00f</item>
   </style>
   ```

Using this method makes it unneccessary to set the theme in the AlertDialog builder.