# Button Theme not working in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

This is what I have in the layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/positive_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/submit_btn_text"
            android:theme="@style/PrimaryRoundedButton"
            tools:style="@style/PrimaryRoundedButton"/>
```

And here's the PrimaryRoundedButton style

```
<style name="PrimaryRoundedButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_button_color</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary_button_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

android:theme isn't working, style works but the ripple is coloured yellow, when it should've been white. The same theme is working in normal fragments, but not dialogFragment.

Comment: Please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422292/how-to-style-buttons-in-alert-dialog-fragment-using-material-design) post and let us know!

Comment: @SaumikBhattacharya I'm not using the positive/negative buttons, but have my own layout, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was setting style in my BaseDialogFragment as

```
setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Light_NoTitleBar);
```

I changed it to

```
setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.FullDialog);
```

Where FullDialog is

```
<style name="FullDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

So now I have a full screen dialog with properly themed buttons.